# Upgrading angular from v15 to v16

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I am upgrading my angular web-app from angular v15 to v16. The Ng-bootstrap used in angular v15 is ng-bootstrap v10, as per documents i have to upgrade my ng-bootstrap to v15 for angular v16. So my question is do i need to upgrade my ng-bootstrap as per document or can i make use of ng-bootstrap v10 for my upgraded angular v16 without seeing any changes to my original UI.

Answer (score 0):

From this [compatibility table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap), for Angular 16 you need ng-bootstrap 15.

ng-bootstrap 10 was intended for Angular 12.

Yes you should update.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to upgrade your ng-bootstrap package to match your angular version, in this case to v15 as you've mentioned. As for the changes you need to make, here's the [changelog](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for ng-bootstrap. Start from v10 and look at all breaking changes till v15. If any of those concern your project, you will need to make appropriate changes.